# SQL Server : exclude table from transaction

Tags: sql-server, transactions, firedac

Is it possible to exclude a complete table from a transaction?

The background is that we have a table which is used as a Next-ID table, so for every other table in the database there is a record in the table which has got the information which ID to use for the next record.

If we start a transaction and this one blocks on record another user can´t use the Next-ID table as it is still blocked.

So it would be nice if the table Next-ID is not blocked during a transaction. If the NextID is 1509 or 1510 or 1984 does not matter at all.

Kind regards

Markus

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2012+, then use a sequence (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx).  By the way, the blocking is important when inserting a new value into your table, to ensure that you don't get duplicates.  It should be blocked for a very short time.

Comment: FireDAC does not offer a feature to exclude a table from a transaction. SQL Server does not offer this feature too. This is rather question to your application design. Probably others will help you with design.

Comment: SQL Server will only lock **one row** (not the whole table) - the one for your table you're getting the next ID for - and that's a *good thing!* You **want** to avoid multiple concurrent updates on that one row!! All other rows are definitely available for other sessions to use.